# How to find third party component being used in a third party library

Tags: java, maven

I have a huge maven project which utilizes a lot of third party libraries. 
When i ran a BlackDuck scan to find the dependencies. It reports back with a library which has a commercial license. I have ran a report manually using mvn dependency:tree but i cannot find this dependency. My assumption now is that some third library is using this component.

How i can find out which one of the 3rd party library is using that 3rd party component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvn dependency:tree` shows **all** dependencies and transitive dependencies of your project, so your 'runtime' doesn't depend on that library. I'm not familiar with BlackDuck at all, but I wonder if it searches for libraries used by plugins too, as that's the only option I can think.

Unfortunately, this is not super easy to check... but what I've done in the past is to delete the library from my local .m2 repo, and then trigger a build with the offline (`-o`) parameter. That should trigger a download, which should fail. The error message should say which plugin depends on the library.